# jQuery: Why is by box collapsing on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery

The homepage of our website (legendboats.com) is 4 small cells, that if you click on, the large image changes. Pretty standard stuff, but there is a problem.

When you click on one of them the first time, the large area collapses before the new image reappears. This doesn't happen again, you can continue to click on different images, and they will fade in and out properly. Here is the code I'm using:

```
$('.home_boxes a.content_box').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var new_slide = this.hash;
    $('#home_box div.active').fadeOut(function() {
        $('#home_box ' + new_slide).fadeIn().addClass('active');
    }).removeClass('active');

});
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong, or any improvements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I don't know why it happens, but I can see the symptoms. For some reason on first click the content collapses. This causes the odd flashing. If you set a min-height on home_box it sorts it out.

```
#home_box { min-height: 482px; }
```

Answer (score 2):

It collapses because you're removing the class="active".

The reason it doesn't collapse after the first time is because jQuery is adding an inline style "display:block" which overrides the missing class="active".

Initially:

```
<div id="standard_equipment" class="active">
```

Subsequently:

```
<div id="more_power" style="display: block;" class="active">
```

Comment: Makes sense. What could I do to fix this? I need the class to be removed, and I need the other boxes hidden.

Comment: The easy solution would be to target the div with a display:block style from the word go (whether you do this with CSS or inline would be up to you). Alternatively, you could make sure the active class is removed at the end rather than at the start of the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this way

```
$('.home_boxes a.content_box').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var new_slide = this.hash;
    $('#home_box div.active').fadeOut(function() {
       var parent = this;
       $('#home_box ' + new_slide).fadeIn(function(){
          //You can shuffle following two lines and try
          $(parent).removeClass('active'); 
          $(this).addClass('active');
       });
    });
});
```

Hope this works you.